# How do you get the filename of a tempfile to use in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Let's say I'm creating a program in C that needs to use a tempfile. Creating an ad hoc tempfile in /tmp is probably not a good idea. Is there a function or OS call to supply me with a tempfile name so that I can begin to write and read from it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`mkstemp(3)`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/mkstemp.3.php) function for this purpose. Another alternative is the [`tmpfile(3)`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/tmpfile.3.php) function.
Which one of them you choose depends on whether you want the file to be opened as a C library file stream (which `tmpfile` does), or a direct file descriptor (`mkstemp`). The `tmpfile` function also deletes the file automatically when you program finishes.

The advantage of using these functions is that they avoid race conditions between determining the unique filename and creating the file -- so that two programs won't try to create the same file at the same time, for example.

See the man pages for both functions for more details.

Comment: mkstemp just returns a file descriptor open on a new file but you also can get it's final name because mkstemp replaces the XXXXXX characters of the template.

Answer (score 6):

The question is how to generate a temporary file **name**.  Neither mkstemp nor tmpfile provide the caller with a name, they return a file descriptor or file handle, respectively.

Comment: You are correct, Mark, the question asks for a temporary file name. But the question is wrong. The questioner doesn't really want a temporary file name, he really wants a temporary file.

Comment: Then the question should be changed.

Comment: Not true: mkstemp *does* provide the caller with a name, since it modifies the template it is given. The caller needs to provide a template, but this is a relatively simple matter of choosing a temporary directory (e.g. $TMPDIR, P_tmpdir, or "/tmp") and a prefix, followed by six X's.

Comment: Ahh, subtle. So the only "good" way to do get a unique filename without actually leaving the file dangling is: 1) call mkstemp with a character buffer that ends in XXXXXX.  2) close the file descriptor mkstemp returns. 3) unlink the filename that mkstemp left in the "template" parameter.   Could it be any less elegant?

Comment: Yeah, I spent quite a while recently coming up with a portable Unix/Windows temp file class. On Linux, you basically have to choose between knowing the filename (mkstemp), and having the file closed automatically for you (tmpfile). On Windows, you have a delete-on-close flag for CreateFile, but no mkstemp and a tmpfile with lots of caveats (root directory?!). In the end, I just wrote my own unique name generator using the crypto PRNG to generate a 128-bit hex suffix.

Comment: @Mark: As soon as you unlink the filename, there's no guarantee it's unique anymore. The problem of trying to get a unique filename without creating it as part of the *same operation* is fundamentally wrong. The existence of the file is needed to serve as a lock.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding Don't forget 1b) Check that the file descriptor is valid (`if (fd < 0) handle_error();`).

Answer (score 3):

@garethm:

> I believe that the function you're looking for is called tmpnam.

You should definitely *not* use `tmpnam`. It suffers from the race condition problem I mentioned in my answer: Between determining the name and opening it, another program may create the file or a symlink to it, which is a huge security hole.

The `tmpnam` man page specifically says not to use it, but to use `mkstemp` or `tmpfile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely: man mkstemp.

The man page has example usage.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about anything in a C lib, but you can do this at the shell with [mktemp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mkstemp() as this is the recommended function, but it returns a file descriptor, so once you have the descriptor get it's name:

```
int fd;
fd = mkstemp("hdrXXXXXX);
/* Read out the link to our file descriptor. */
sprintf(path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));
readlink(path, result, sizeof(result)-1);

/* Print the result. */
printf("%s\n", result);
```

Comment: Please chekc this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: .. this will only work if you send it to another thread in your own process (or if you send it to your own thread), it won't work if you send it to another process with a different `/proc/self` - instead use `/dev/fd/%d` , then it will work both with threads within your own process, AND different processes

Answer (score 0):

usually there's no need to actually make a named file; instead use the file descriptor path,

```c
FILE *tmp=tmpfile();
char path[PATH_MAX+1]={0};
sprintf(path, "/dev/fd/%d", fileno(tmp));
printf("%s\n", path);
```